# Is it possible to get CA pub key only with cert-manager?

Tags: cert-manager

I recently migrated to Google CAS and cert-manager and it is working great. I have an interesting need for which I can't find answer for, so here I am seeking the communities wisdom.

I wanted to validate a cert presented to me is coming from the CA, for this my service needs the CA's pub key. Is it possible to get only the CA public key through cert-manager?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you able to access the resource?